# Python GDAL: Rasterising point data, raster and points are not geolocated

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to rasterise some point data using Python GDAL module. But when I plot the data there is an offset between the two (original points and raster). I am sure it has to do with the geotransform values.

Here is my code and data can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4akb5vwu0dgvf68/SAMPLE_POINTS.csv?dl=0).

```
import pandas as pd
import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pts = pd.read_csv("SAMPLE_POINTS.csv")

# here I grid the data and count how many points are in each cell
pts['XX'] = pts.X // 10000
pts['YY'] = pts.Y // 10000

COUNT = np.empty((len(pts.XX.unique()), len(pts.YY.unique())))

for i, XX in enumerate(np.sort(pts.XX.unique())):
    for j, YY in enumerate(np.sort(pts.YY.unique())):
        c = pts.ix[(pts.XX > XX) & (pts.XX <= XX + 1) & 
                   (pts.YY > YY) & (pts.YY <= YY + 1)]
        COUNT[i, j] = len(c)

# Setting gt is the bit I am sure is wrong
# This is taken from SetGeoTransform() I would use to export raster
gt = [pts.X.min(), 10000, 0, pts.Y.max(), 0, -10000]

# plot raster
cmap = plt.imshow(np.ma.masked_equal(np.rot90(COUNT), 0), interpolation="none", 
                  extent=(gt[0], gt[0] + (gt[1] * COUNT.shape[0]), 
                          gt[3] - (gt[1] * COUNT.shape[1]), gt[3]))
plt.colorbar(cmap)

# plot points
plt.scatter(pts.X, pts.Y, s=1, c='k', edgecolor="none")

# close up of misalignment
plt.xlim(450000, 500000)
plt.ylim(5850000, 5900000)
plt.show()
```

I don't think it is plotting the data in Python that is wrong because when I export the raster and display in a GIS there is the same offset.

Here are a few of images illustrating the offset. The points and the rasters are orientated correctly but the raster is offset south by maybe 2 pixels.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "offset"? Is the raster flipped in the N-S direction? That's a [known issue](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3986) with the GDAL XYZ driver. You can easily fix by running the raster through `gdalwarp` or using `gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(gdal.Dataset)` in python.

Comment: Thanks @luke, the image is orientated correctly - I have added images to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out there were two lines wrong in my code. The first is the line which selects the points iteratively from the pandas dataframe which should be:

```
c = pts.ix[(pts.XX == XX) & (pts.YY == YY)]
```

Before it was selecting point from the next grid cell and attributing them to the previous cell.

The second error was in the geotransform line which should be:

```
gt = [(pts.XX.min() * 10000), 10000, 0, (pts.YY.max() * 10000) + 10000, 0, -10000]
```

The `+10000` in the 4th item shifts the raster up one pixel. I'm not completely sure why this is needed, I think it has to do with the coordinate needs to refer to the (top?) of the upper left pixel (see [here](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#af9593cc241e7d140f5f3c4798a43a668)).

Anyway as you can see the points and the raster now align.

[image]
[image]